# Flutter animated splash screen using Lottie animations - width and height of animation cannot be resized

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am pretty new to Flutter, and I have been trying to implement an animation I found on Lottie for a splash screen. I have been running into some issues with resizing.

In my code below, I am using the resizing suggestions from the [Flutter documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie). When I do not put the line “fit: BoxFit.fill”, the animation remains tiny even when I change the width and height constraints [Without "fit: BoxFit.fill”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuudS.png).

However, when I have the line “fit: BoxFit.fill”, the animation is horizontally stretched even when I change the height constraints [With "fit: BoxFit.fill”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHEI3.png).

I have been trying a lot with different width and height values but nothing seems to work. I saw other posts on here with people who had similar issues, but their solutions have not worked for me. I already tried [trimming the borders](https://dealfonso.github.io/simplelottieplayer/lottietrimmer.html), adding a SizedBox + Overflow Box, putting in a Scaffold widget, and putting it in an Expanded widget.

I also am having trouble getting my splash transition and page transition to work. Is there any reason why the animations are not working? Lastly, I’m interested in adding text with my app name on the splash screen once I get the sizing fixed. I tried using a Column widget, but I always had a bottom overflow error. Is a Column widget the right one to use or which one should I use?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
      splash: Center(
        child: Lottie.asset(
          'assets/splash_screen_animation.json',
          width: 400,
          height: 4000,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      duration: 4000,
      pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade,
      splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
      nextScreen: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try bounding it by a container instead of using center widget and remove width and height from the Lottie widget.